# Using MYSQL AES_ENCRYPT function with PDO but wrong and different string format

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

here is my QUERY

```
SELECT client_id,client_name,client_db_ip,client_db_username,AES_ENCRYPT(client_db_pass, '1234') as client_db_pass,client_db_name FROM client_list WHERE client_id =:id
```

//pls focus on AES_ENCRYPT(client_db_pass, '1234') as client_db_pass

now if i query directly using phpmyadmin, i will get the result eg for client_db_pass after AES_ENCRYPT:

```
501defc4013f3f21529c123f33c065ad
```

But the problem come when iam using PDO to fetch the data,

```
        $Q = "SELECT client_id,client_name,client_db_ip,client_db_username,AES_ENCRYPT(client_db_pass, '1234') as client_db_pass,client_db_name FROM client_list WHERE client_id =:id";
    $R = $this->pdo->prepare($Q);
    $R->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $R->execute();
    $result = $R->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

if i var_dump($result)

i will get this result:

```
array (size=6)
'client_id' => string '1' (length=1)
'client_name' => string 'tester' (length=4)
'client_db_ip' => string '127.0.0.2' (length=9)
'client_db_username' => string 'root' (length=4)
'client_db_pass' => string 'PïÄ??!Rœ?3Àe­' (length=16)
'client_db_name' => string 'test_user' (length=9)
```

can you see the array for 'client_db_pass' string is

```
result 2 = PïÄ??!Rœ?3Àe­
```

not

```
result 1 = 501defc4013f3f21529c123f33c065ad
```

may i know how to get result 1 "501defc4013f3f21529c123f33c065ad" if using pdo?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`AES_ENCRYPT()`, according to [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt), returns binary data:

> returns a binary string containing the encrypted output.

If you see anything else in your MySQL client it's because the client encodes the raw output automatically.

In PHP you can get an hexadecimal dump with e.g. [bin2hex()](http://php.net/bin2hex) and in MySQL you can do it with [HEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_hex). I don't think you need it though, both MySQL and PHP handle binary just fine.